# show file without a text from a file using grep

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, grep

I'm trying to remove a long text of various lines contained in a file from another file.

I've tried with

```
egrep -v $(cat text) original
```

with no success....

Comment: Use `grep -vFf test original`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `-f pattern-file` option in `grep`:

```
grep -vxFf test original
```

- `x` is for exact pattern match (remove this if you want partial match also)
- `F` is for fixed string search instead of regex